# Racket : How can I turn a stream into a list?

Tags: racket

In Racket, how can I turn a stream into a list?

I assumed that there'd be a common interface, but it seems that list oriented functions like map don't work on streams. So how can I turn them into lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a procedure for that: [`stream->list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-~3elist%29%29). For example:

```
(define s (stream 1 2 3 4 5))
(stream->list s)
=> '(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Make sure to check the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html), there are several procedures for manipulating streams that mirror the ones available for lists.

Answer (score 3):

There's a straightforwardly-named [`stream->list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-~3elist%29%29) function.  It's provided from the [`racket/stream`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html) library, and you can see many other list-like functions for streams, including `stream-map`.

(But if you're using that, note that this library can have severe performance penalties over using streams as is.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [`stream->list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html?q=sequence-%3Elist#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-~3elist%29%29), there's also a more general [`sequence->list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=sequence-%3Elist#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsequence..rkt%29._sequence-~3elist%29%29) that turns any [`sequence?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=sequence-%3Elist#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._sequence~3f%29%29) into a list.

```
> (sequence->list (stream 1 2 3))
'(1 2 3)
> (sequence->list "abc")
'(#\a #\b #\c)
> (sequence->list (set 1 2 3))
'(1 2 3)
```